# Extracting JavaScript into separate file (from HTML). Duplicate call to function needed

Tags: javascript

See the source of http://marakana.com/s/post/1096/samples/try6.htm
It defines a function and calls it on load of document. (Which is the final step of [this tutorial](http://marakana.com/s/post/1096/using_the_html5_attribute_contenteditable_to_create_a_wysiwyg))

I tried to put it into a seperate JS file.
Runs correctly only if I call onload both in JS and in HTML.
But not only body onload or only from JS. I guess I am doing something wrong.
So, following works:

```
<head>
<script src="Scripts/makeWYSIWYG.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () {
               makeWYSIWYG(document.getElementById('editor'));
            };
</script>
</head>
<body onload="makeWYSIWYG(document.getElementById('editor'));">
```

Why do I need to call the function twice?

I only have the function definition in "Scripts/makeWYSIWYG.js" 
    function makeWYSIWYG(editor) {
    ...
        return editor;
    };

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually the closing tag, "/>", here:

```
<script src="Scripts/makeWYSIWYG.js" type="text/javascript"/>
```

I should have written:

```
<script src="Scripts/makeWYSIWYG.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

I guess the second script was helping the tag to be closed and making it run...

More info here: [Why don't self-closing script tags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

Answer (score 0):

There are no reason to call the function twice. The  is enough.

With the first  window.onload you could be changing a former function callback assignment (i.e. in a imported script).